# Uncheck conversion on returning class type

Tags: java, spring, generics, wicket-7, wicketstuff

I have a method that returns a class type, and it is working right.
The problem is... I am getting some compilation warnings indicating unchecked conversion.

*Below is the warning message I got:*

```
Warning: java: getAjaxEventPayloadClass() in <anonymous com.iyotbihagay.wicket.panel.requestpage.resultlist.ResultList2$7> implements <P>getAjaxEventPayloadClass() in com.iyotbihagay.wicket.panel.paging.Paging.Support
  return type requires unchecked conversion from java.lang.Class<com.iyotbihagay.wicket.support.RefreshSearchResultEventPayload> to java.lang.Class<P>
```

even if I use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` I still cannot get rid of the compilation warning.

Below are some of the codes pointing to the warning:

**ResultList2.java**

```
public class ResultList2 {
    ...
    private Component createPaging() {
        return new Paging("paging", getRequestPageContext(), new Paging.Support() {
            @Override
            public void switchPage(AjaxRequestTarget target, int targetPageNum) {
                getRequestPageContext().switchPage(target, targetPageNum);
            }
            @Override
            public int getTotalNum() {
                return getSearchResult().getTotalNum();
            }
            @Override
            public int getPageSize() {
                return getSearchResult().getPageSize();
            }
            @Override
            public int getLastPageNum() {
                return getSearchResult().getLastPageNum();
            }
            @Override
            public int getCurrentPageNum() {
                return getSearchResult().getCurrentPageNum();
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Class<RefreshSearchResultEventPayload> getAjaxEventPayloadClass() {
                return RefreshSearchResultEventPayload.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void decorateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes, String pageNumMarkupId) {
                decorateAjaxRefreshSearchResult(attributes, pageNumMarkupId);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**Support.java**

```
public static interface Support extends Serializable {
    ...
    <P extends AjaxEventPayload> Class<P> getAjaxEventPayloadClass();
    ...
}
```

**Paging.java**

```
public class Paging {
    ...
    private Support m_support;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event) {
        super.onEvent(event);
        WicketUtil.onEvent(event, m_support.getAjaxEventPayloadClass(), new AjaxEventHandler<AjaxEventPayload>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(IEvent<?> event, AjaxRequestTarget target, AjaxEventPayload paymentLoad) {
                m_firstPageNumModel.detach();
                m_previousPageNumModel.detach();
                m_nextPageNumModel.detach();
                m_lastPageNumModel.detach();
                target.add(m_container);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

**WicketUtil.java**

```
public class WicketUtil {
    ...
    public static <P extends AjaxEventPayload> void onEvent(IEvent<?> event, Class<P> targetPayload, AjaxEventHandler<P> handler) {
        if (event.getPayload() != null) {
            if (targetPayload.isAssignableFrom(event.getPayload().getClass())) {
                P p = (AjaxEventPayload)event.getPayload();
                handler.onEvent(event, p.getTarget(), p);
            }

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`m_support.getAjaxEventPayloadClass()` is called/passed on `WicketUtil.onEvent()`... specifically on the second parameter.
`RefreshSearchResultEventPayload` is just one of the classes that extends `AjaxEventPayload` and there are other classes that extends to `AjaxEventPayload`and are passed to `WicketUtil.onEvent()`.

Answer (score 2):

This should rather be:

```
public static interface Support extends Serializable {
    ...
    Class<? extends AjaxEventPayload> getAjaxEventPayloadClass();
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class ResultList2 {
    ...
    @Override
    public Class<RefreshSearchResultEventPayload> getAjaxEventPayloadClass() {
        return RefreshSearchResultEventPayload.class;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

The reason is that `<P extends AjaxEventPayload>` means that the method can return a class of arbitrary payload type (as requested by the caller), e.g.:

```
support.<AjaxEventPayload>getAjaxEventPayloadClass()
```

instead of returning only the one payload type that is specific to the implementing class (e.g. `RefreshSearchResultEventPayload`).